# How should I store the map in a game?

Tags: java

I am building a simple 2D game in Java, but I cannot decide how to store the map data. I want something like arrays, however global arrays in Java are static, and they cannot be dynamic sized. I am going to load the map from a file, however, sometimes the maps are differently sized.

Hashmap looks too complicated for what I want. **What would be a good way to store the data easily?** I want to create a simple method to retrieve the data for each coordinate.

Example:

```
int blockdata = blockCheck(5, 8);
```

It would then return the data "5a7" or whatever the data is. In similar games I have just had static variables in an array, but I do not know how to do this being dynamically sized.

Comment: Use the Hashmap, it is the simplest way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Sibbo: Hashmap is pretty inefficient for indexed storage. You can do much better with arrays or ArrayLists

Comment: Well, the Hashmap has no size boundary and you can read to and write from it in one line. Since he asked about simplicity and not efficiency, it is not the worst choice. Of course, an array would be faster, but resizing arrays is inefficient again. The best way would be to use a TreeMap or Hashmap of chunks, like Minecraft does... Then you can load and unload those chunks as you need and you can use maps of any size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally I would recommend creating a custom `Map` class, that **encapsulates** the storage in private members. That way, if you change the internal storage, the rest of your code can still work unchanged. You can give the Map a nice APi so you can do stuff like `map.get(10,12)` and `map.set(3,4,BRICK_WALL);` etc.

For the internal storage you have a few choices / techniques to choose between:

- Use nested data structures: an `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists`s is fine to represent a 2D map, and allows for dynamic resizing
- Use an existing lower-level library that provides 2D Map storage
- Use nested arrays like `Tile[][]` or similar. If you want to create a new map, you'll need to create a new nested array of course, but this is generally not a problem.
- Use a flat array `Tile[]` or similar, and compute index locations into this array. You can compute unique indexes with something like `array[x + y * columnCount]`.

Personally, I'd probably go for arrays. They are the most lightweight and efficient, and I think dynamic sizing is generally unnecessary: if you need maps of different sizes just create a new `Map` of the required size each time.

Answer (score 2):

> I want something like arrays, however global arrays in Java are static, and they cannot be dynamic sized. I am going to load the map from a file, however, sometimes the maps are differently sized.

You can add a class member and initialize it with dynamic value in the constructor i.e. when you create it's object

```
class Map {
      int[][] twodspace;
      Map(){}
      Map(int len, int width){
         twodspace = new int[len][width];
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have an ArrayList of ArrayLists. For example:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myarray= new ArrayList<>();

int blockCheck(int x, int y) {
    return myarray.get(x).get(y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using a data structure based on tree maps, mainly because it's relatively sparse in my case and I need to be able to iterate in order:

```
public class Grid<T> implements Iterable<T> {
  private TreeMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,T>> data = new TreeMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,T>>();

  public T get(int row, int col) {
    TreeMap<Integer,T> r = data.get(row);
    return r == null ? null : r.get(col);
  }

  public void set(int row, int col, T value) {
    TreeMap<Integer,T> r = data.get(row);
    if (r == null) {
      r = new TreeMap<Integer, T>();
      data.put(row, r);
    }
    r.put(col, value);
  }
}
```

I'd recommend to have a similar level of abstraction (your own 2d "Grid" backed by whatever data structure that suits your needs best), so you can easily tweak the underlying implementation (array, tree, hasmap, whatever) based on your needs without having to change the rest of the application code.

Answer (score 0):

I just used a txt file with structure like this:

```
*
*               + + 
*    ____
*
**************************
```

And then I was just processing the file. Simplest way there was for me. Then for example + character is something, - is something etc.

Comment: But if you would later need to look at this file how would you without reading it again from the disk and wasting how much resources on a bigger map? That's where I got stuck.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question

Comment: I'm just saying accessing the file repeatedly is really inefficient. It should be stored in variables (in RAM) so it is easier to access and it should be stored efficiently so I don't have to sort through the whole file. I'm just doing this project to build a base for a much bigger game. If I have a 500x500 map all in one file which gets accessed 3 times a second, that is a lot of data to be sorted through that could be much more efficient if stored on RAM then on the HDD.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, this is only the way for storing the particular level in a file, and loading the data from it before the level starts, I never meant constant reading of the file while playing :)